# Why does PySpark fail with random "Socket is closed" error?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I just went through a PySpark training course and I'm compiling a script of example lines of code (which explains why the code block does nothing).  Every time I run this code, I get this error once or twice.  The line which throws it changes between runs.  I've tried setting `spark.executor.memory` and `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval`, but the error persists.  I've also tried putting `.cache()` at the end of various lines, with no changes.

The error:

```
16/09/21 10:29:32 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for python
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at java.net.Socket.shutdownOutput(Socket.java:1551)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply$mcV$sp(PythonRDD.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PythonRDD.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PythonRDD.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLog(Utils.scala:1870)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1857)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:269)
```

The code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

def parseLine(line):
    fields = line.split(',')
    return (int(fields[0]), float(fields[2]))

def parseGraphs(line):
    fields = line.split()
    return (fields[0]), [int(n) for n in fields[1:]]

# putting the [*] after local makes it run one executor on each core of your local PC
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("MyProcessName")

sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

# parse the raw data and map it to an rdd.
# each item in this rdd is a tuple
# two methods to get the exact same data:
########## All of these methods can use lambda or full methods in the same way ##########
# read in a text file
customerOrdersLines = sc.textFile("file:///SparkCourse/customer-orders.csv")
customerOrdersRdd = customerOrdersLines.map(parseLine)
customerOrdersRdd = customerOrdersLines.map(lambda l: (int(l.split(',')[0]), float(l.split(',')[2])))
print customerOrdersRdd.take(1)

# countByValue groups identical values and counts them
salesByCustomer = customerOrdersRdd.map(lambda sale: sale[0]).countByValue()
print salesByCustomer.items()[0]

# use flatMap to cut everything up by whitespace
bookText = sc.textFile("file:///SparkCourse/Book.txt")
bookRdd = bookText.flatMap(lambda l: l.split())
print bookRdd.take(1)

# create key/value pairs that will allow for more complex uses
names = sc.textFile("file:///SparkCourse/marvel-names.txt")
namesRdd = names.map(lambda line: (int(line.split('\"')[0]), line.split('\"')[1].encode("utf8")))
print namesRdd.take(1)

graphs = sc.textFile("file:///SparkCourse/marvel-graph.txt")
graphsRdd = graphs.map(parseGraphs)
print graphsRdd.take(1)

# this will append "extra text" to each name.
# this is faster than a normal map because it doesn't give you access to the keys
extendedNamesRdd = namesRdd.mapValues(lambda heroName: heroName + "extra text")
print extendedNamesRdd.take(1)

# not the best example because the costars is already a list of integers
# but this should return a list, which will update the values
flattenedCostarsRdd = graphsRdd.flatMapValues(lambda costars: costars)
print flattenedCostarsRdd.take(1)

# put the heroes in ascending index order
sortedHeroes = namesRdd.sortByKey()
print sortedHeroes.take(1)

# to sort heroes by alphabetical order, we switch key/value to value/key, then sort
alphabeticalHeroes = namesRdd.map(lambda (key, value): (value, key)).sortByKey()
print alphabeticalHeroes.take(1)

# make sure that "spider" is in the name of the hero
spiderNames = namesRdd.filter(lambda (id, name): "spider" in name.lower())
print spiderNames.take(1)

# reduce by key keeps the key and performs aggregation methods on the values.  in this example, taking the sum
combinedGraphsRdd = flattenedCostarsRdd.reduceByKey(lambda value1, value2: value1 + value2)
print combinedGraphsRdd.take(1)

# broadcast: this is accessible from any executor
sentData = sc.broadcast(["this can be accessed by all executors", "access it using sentData"])

# accumulator:  this is synced across all executors
hitCounter = sc.accumulator(0)
```

Comment: Could you tell at which step does it return the error ? Does any of you print works ?

Comment: You've probably confused the source and destination port. Default connection pattern `Any(available) >> Target Port`, Perhaps the default port is 80, then you cannot connect to the 80 ports. I strongly advise you to check the client and server connection with Wireshark.

Comment: What's the Spark version? Can you fire up `pyspark` and type some commands without the error? It's Windows, isn't it? How do you execute the above code?

Comment: Do you have python installed on your machine?

Answer (score 2):

**DISCLAIMER:** I haven't spent enough time on that part of Spark's codebase, but let me give you *some* hints that may lead to a solution. What follows is just to explain where to search for more information not a solution to the issue.

---

The exception you are facing is due to some other issue as seen in the code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/python/PythonRunner.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L219-L225) (as you may see by the line `java.net.Socket.shutdownOutput(Socket.java:1551)` which is when `worker.shutdownOutput()` is executed).

```
16/09/21 10:29:32 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for python
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at java.net.Socket.shutdownOutput(Socket.java:1551)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply$mcV$sp(PythonRDD.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PythonRDD.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PythonRDD.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLog(Utils.scala:1870)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1857)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:269)
```

That leads me to believe that the ERROR is a follow-up to some other earlier error.

The name **stdout writer for python** is [the name of the thread](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/python/PythonRunner.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L135) that (uses [EvalPythonExec](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/python/EvalPythonExec.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L60) physical operator and) is responsible for the communication between Spark and pyspark (so you can execute python code without much changes).

As a matter of fact [the scaladoc of `EvalPythonExec`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/python/EvalPythonExec.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L34-L60) gives quite a lot of information on the underlying communication infrastructure that pyspark uses internally and that uses sockets to an external Python process.

> Python evaluation works by sending the necessary (projected) input data via a socket to an external Python process, and combine the result from the Python process with the original row.

Moreover, `python` is used by default unless overriden using `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` or `PYSPARK_PYTHON` (as you can see in `pyspark` shell script [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/pyspark#L27-L31) and [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/pyspark#L53)). That's the name that appears in the name of the thread that fails.

> 16/09/21 10:29:32 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for **python**

I'd recommend checking out the version of python on your system using the following command.

```
python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version_info)'
```

[That should be Python 2.7+](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/pyspark#L45), but could be that you use the very latest Python that is not well tested with Spark. *Guessing...*

---

You should include the entire log of the pyspark application's execution and that's where I'd expect to find the answer.